# how can I get the last child item of a mat-accordion element in material-ui, angular 8

Tags: typescript, material-ui, angular8

I have several expansion panels in a mat-accordion element, which are dynamically generated. I want to select the last mat-expansion-panel element in order to expand it. How can I do that?

```html
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    text 0
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    text 1
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    text 2
  </mat-expansion-panel>
...
</mat-accordion>
<button (click)="addNewItemAndExpandIt()">Add item and expand it</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using ngFor **last** like that

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let expansion of expansionPanels; last as lastExpansion;" [expanded]="lastExpansion">
    text 0
  </mat-expansion-panel>
...
</mat-accordion>
```

**EDIT 1**

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfxgop)

Comment: my button is out of the mat-expansion-panel, so it doesn't work. `last` cannot be found

Comment: Find the stackBlitz demo in updated answer. I think you are trying to achieve the same thing.

Comment: It works. that's what I want, thank you for your demo, it's very helpful!